# Why ImportError: No module named lightgbm

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning, lightgbm

My OS is Ubuntu, and I've followed the official installation [guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/wiki/Installation-Guide) to install lightgbm. However, when I import it, this error is raised:

> ImportError: No module named lightgbm

How can I solve this?

Do I also need to go to /python-package folder to run setup.py after running those linux commandlines?

Comment: can you share the code you are using?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf The same as the official guide:git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM ; cd LightGBM
mkdir build ; cd build
cmake .. 
make -j

Comment: are you getting this error while installing? I mean share the code when you import this library.

Comment: There is no error during the installation. My import code is: import lightgbm as lgb

Comment: how are you running this code?

Comment: Just type 'python' to enter python environment and import . I've tried import both on default and anaconda environment. Both of them have this error

Comment: do you have python2 and python3 in your os?

Comment: no. just python2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides running those linux command lines. I also need to go to `/python-package` then run 'python setup.py install'.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, and solved running the installation directly on the notebook

```
!pip install lightgbm
```

Answer (score 2):

`conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm` solved the problem for me
you need just run in a notebook cell before importing

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users,  `VC runtime <https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746572>` is needed if Visual Studio (2015 or 2017) is not installed.

Install `wheel <http://pythonwheels.com>` via `pip install wheel` first. After that download the wheel file and install from it:

```
pip install lightgbm
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/anaconda3/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Note that you might need to change the paths if you are using a different Python version.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for above question and answers, had a similar issue.

**Problem:**

After successfull install of `lightgbm`, I was getting the error `ImportError: No module named 'lightgbm'` (in Jupyter Notebook on Google Cloud's Notebook Instance in AI Platform project).

**Issue:**

Realized that the install of `lightgbm` was in `Python 2.7` even when the notebook was running in `Python 3` (path: '`./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`').

**Solution:**

The error was gone after the Jupyter Notebook was set to run on Python 2 instead of Python 3.

Comment: I solved the error by:  pip3 install lightgbm

Answer (score 0):

within Jupyter Notebook cell is: try running

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install lightgbm
```

With python try, from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/lightgbm/), this line

```
pip install lightgbm
```

or

```
pip3 install lightgbm
```

Also, you can try this one if you use anaconda

```
conda install lightgbm
```